# Adding an image in UWP?

Tags: c#, image, xaml, uwp

I have been looking online for hours trying to find a way to insert a simple image into my Universal Windows Application. All the tutorials I have found so far have been too confusing or just don't work.

Is there a way to insert an image into my XAML page that can be explained for someone new to developing Windows Apps? Do I need to initialize it in XAML and C#, or just through XAML?

Comment: Where did you look? Why was it confusing?

Comment: @Clemens K I'm a beginner no reason to rage uncontrollably.

Comment: That shouldn't stop you from googling the most simple things. The web has plenty of detailed information, especially for beginners.

Answer (score 9):

Since I cannot comment yet, I'll answer this.

In order to add an image to your XAML you simply have to add a  tag. So the code would look like this:

```
<Image Source="Assets/example.jpg"/>
```

I would suggest you follow this beginner series for UWP. I found it great for showing me the basics of XAML and teaching me a bit of the new design language. Just know that it's almost a year old and there are tiny tweaks, especially with design. Nothing to worry about though, just keep it in mind.

Comment: I don't know why but this won't work for me, at all. I had to use 

`<Image Source="ms-appx:/Assets/example.jpg"/>`

Comment: The path `Assets/example.jpg` is relative to the `.xaml` file that your `Image` element resides in. If you use `ms-appx:` namespace, than it's an absolute path. So in your case maybe `../Assets/example.jpg` would work if your `XAML` file is in a sibling folder with Assets.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, where I only needed to just add simple picture get it over with, I'm assuming that you are using VS2017 if no, then I don't know if this solution will work, but if you are using VS2017 then do the following

fist add an image element for example `<Image x:Name="img1" Width="100" Height="100"  />`

in the Universal Apps, there is a folder called `Assets` you will find it in the solution folder, also in the solution explorer,
[image]
 right click on it in the solution explorer -> add existing item -> the photo you want

after you have added the photo, go to the `img1` prosperities and in the source you will find the photo that was added inside the drop down list, keep in mind that there is already images in the assets

[image]
 you will find that the path for the image is added automatically in the `Source` attribute to the control `img1`
for example `<Image x:Name="img1" Width="100" Height="100" Source="Assets/1.jpg"  />`

Answer (score 3):

Remember that when you want to insert a new image into Assets, you must go into the solution explorer, Assets->Add->New Item. If you insert the image manually, then you need to Add->existing item. Then select the image, rigth click, properties and in Build Action, make sure "content" is the default.

Answer (score 0):

If you get confused about anything you can just download a sample and follow how it works (I get bored easily so I do that myself, and set up couple of break points to understand the code flow),

Try this:
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/0f5d56ae-5e57-48e1-9cd9-993115b027b9

Comment: Thanks, this did it! I added it to my desktop repo only, and low and behold, my Assets folder on Solution Explorer was empty. Also, tried to drag and drop into that folder and it was still not showing, then did the "add existing item" like you suggested and it worked!